# put gulp spawn git log into file

Tags: javascript, git, gulp

I have the following output:

```
gulp.task('log', function () {
  spawn('git', ['log', '-20', '--pretty=format:"%h - %an, %ai : %s <br\>'], {stdio: 'inherit'});
});
```

And I want to save it to a file. How can I achive that?

I am new to gulp, tried to use this:

```
gulp.task('log', function() {
  require('fs').writeFileSync('myGitLog.txt', spawn('git', ['log', '-20', '--pretty=format:"%h - %an, %ai : %s <br\>'],  {stdio: 'inherit'}))
});
```

but it put '[object Object] into the files.

My other approach was this:

```
gulp.task('log', function() {
  const text = spawn('git', ['log', '-20', '--pretty=format:"%h - %an, %ai : %s <br\>'],  {stdio: 'inherit'});
  return file('myGitLog.txt', text, {src: true})
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
```

But this gave me the following error:

```
TypeError: First argument must be a string, Buffer, ArrayBuffer, Array, or array-like object.
   at Function.Buffer.from (buffer.js:161:9)
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a possible solution using [shell task](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-shell):

```
gulp.task('log', shell.task([
  'git log -20 --pretty=format:"%h - %an, %ai : %s <br/>" > "valami.txt"'
]));
```